# Whats the recipe for a safe enviroment to create/play with my web applications.

Tags: python, heroku, flask

How can i create a safe environment to create new and play with my web applications?

My ingredients so far: python,flask,github,heroku --- I have effectively created a app using flask and heroku (it just says hello world)

I have some knowledge of python. Have read through but hardly understand the flaskr tutorial for Flask. I do however envision that i'm going to be very frustrated if i can't have some kind of version history of my stumblings.

Without being sure i feel like the recipe might include: Github and virtualenv and some coping pasting of directories...

whats a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup a GitHub repository and start hacking away with Flask.

Some pointers:

- Use [SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html) for database operations. It's secure and easy to use.
- Either dive right into your project or make some simple test ones with Flask. It's a really beautiful framework to work with and is easy to learn, so just try to accomplish some simple tasks and get used to how it works.

Comment: [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/index.html) is another option if you do not want to go all the way out to Heroku for simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/), this way you can work on isolated pythons without filling your system's python with many eggs and switch between them easily.